# aiogram магические фильтры

Tags: python, aiogram

вопрос: как называется магический фильтр, проверяющий наличие документа в сообщении пользователя? и да, если не сложно, скиньте пожалуйста документацию где это можно посмотреть, просто в официальной ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Как и с остальными - `F.document`

В документации указано [тут](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html)

Comment: спасибо. момент: в документации не сказано ни про F.document ни про то, как сделать проверку на тип файла (txt,mp4,mp3 и тд). вопрос: как проверить какой файл отправил пользователь?

Comment: @indominus, непосредственно про F.document не сказано, там, в принципе, несколько примеров. Но сказано как они образуются. Средствами aiogram тип файла не проверить, используйте python, к примеру, os.path.splitext()